# Regex time,date,id

Tags: python, regex

We're using the same syslog, and we want to display the date, time, and process id that's inside the square brackets. We can read each line of the syslog and pass the contents to the `show_time_of_pid` function.

```py
import re

def show_time_of_pid(line):


    pattern=r"^(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec).*\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\[(\d+)\]"
    result = re.search(pattern, line)

    return result
```

This:

```py
print(show_time_of_pid("Jul 6 14:01:23 computer.name CRON[29440]: USER (good_user)"))
```

Should print:

```
Jul 6 14:01:23 pid:29440
```

What do we miss in `show_time_of_pid` implementation?

Comment: Please fix formatting and what exactly is your question?

Comment: Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

```py
import re
def show_time_of_pid(line):
  pattern = r"(^\b[A-Za-z]{3}\b [1-9] \b[\d]{2}:[\d]{2}:[\d]{2}\b) [\w].*\[([\d]+)\]"
  result = re.search(pattern, line)
  return "{} pid:{}".format(result[1],result[2])
```

(please make sure you take note of spacing to match easily)

break down:
the brackets () in the pattern is to separate the input string into groups so they I obtain indexes to extract the result

1. `^\b[A-Za-z]{3}\b` : matches first three letters that is jul ( ^ means starting with, `\b \b` mean exact match , `{3}` means first 3 matching elements
2. `[1-9] \b[\d]{2}:[\d]{2}:[\d]{2}\b` : `[1-9]` - matches a single digit 1-9 ,`\b[\d]{2}:[\d]{2}:[\d]{2}\b` - matches exactly any time in format xx:xx:xx i.e 02:15:67 ,`{2}` - means only 2 digit
3. `[\w].*\[([\d]+)\]` : `[\w].*` matches all other alpha-numeric character afterwards (note the `.*` help with all other matching word including spaces), `\[([\d]+)\]` - `\d` is for digits  and why `\[` is to match exactly the square bracket , also the `[\d]+` is to match more numbers in the range

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues in your code:

- `[` and `]` should be escaped in regex pattern as those are special symbols (indicates a set of characters).
- You did not use a group for date and time, so you won't be able to get it from the result later.
- You did not try getting those groups (there is actually a group for the month and for the pid) from the search result. You just tried to print the search result object.

I would recommend reading the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) about `[]` and groups. Also [HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) is great at this time of the year.

Here is a working example:

```py
import re

def show_time_of_pid(line):
  pattern=r"^(?P<date_time>(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\s+\d{,2}\s+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).*\[(?P<pid>\d+)\]"
  re_result = re.search(pattern, line)

  result = f"{re_result.group('date_time')} pid:{re_result.group('pid')}"

  return result

print(show_time_of_pid("Jul 6 14:01:23 computer.name CRON[29440]: USER (good_user)"))
```

Output:

```
Jul 6 14:01:23 pid:29440
```

Answer (score 0):

simple solution

```
def show_time_of_pid(line):

    date_pattern = r'\w+ \d (\d:?)+'
    date_result = re.search(date_pattern, line)

    pid_pattern = r'\[(\d+)\]'
    pid_result = re.search(pid_pattern, line)

    if date_result == None or pid_result == None :
        return "None"

    return '{} pid:{}'.format(date_result[0], pid_result[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^(\w+)([\d: ]+).*(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).*\[(\d+)\]
```

I made 4 groups, 1st for month, 2nd for the date, 3rd for the time, and the 4th for pid.

Answer (score 0):

this is my solution. In the quotation marks, the first parentheses expression is group(1) the second is group(2) and the third is group(3), we only need group 1 and 3.

```
    import re
    def show_time_of_pid(line):
        pattern = r"(^\w* .\d*.\d*:\d*:\d+)(.*)\[(\d+)\]"
        result = re.search(pattern, line)
        return "{} pid:{}".format(result.group(1), result.group(3))

    print(show_time_of_pid("Jul 6 14:01:23 computer.name CRON[29440]: USER (good_user)"))
```

Output:

Jul 6 14:01:23 pid:29440

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
   def show_time_of_pid(line):
        pattern = r'^(\w+ [0-9] [0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+) [\w\.]+ [\w=]+\[([0-9]+)\]'
        result = re.search(pattern, line)
        return "{} pid:{} ".format(result[1], result[2])

  print(show_time_of_pid("Jul 6 14:01:23 computer.name CRON[29440]: USER (good_user)")) # Jul 6 14:01:23 pid:29440

  print(show_time_of_pid("Jul 6 14:02:08 computer.name jam_tag=psim[29187]: (UUID:006)")) # Jul 6 14:02:08 pid:29187

  print(show_time_of_pid("Jul 6 14:02:09 computer.name jam_tag=psim[29187]: (UUID:007)")) # Jul 6 14:02:09 pid:29187

  print(show_time_of_pid("Jul 6 14:03:01 computer.name CRON[29440]: USER (naughty_user)")) # Jul 6 14:03:01 pid:29440

  print(show_time_of_pid("Jul 6 14:03:40 computer.name cacheclient[29807]: start syncing from \"0xDEADBEEF\"")) # Jul 6 14:03:40 pid:29807

  print(show_time_of_pid("Jul 6 14:04:01 computer.name CRON[29440]: USER (naughty_user)")) # Jul 6 14:04:01 pid:29440

  print(show_time_of_pid("Jul 6 14:05:01 computer.name CRON[29440]: USER (naughty_user)")) # Jul 6 14:05:01 pid:29440
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend having a look at [`Logstash`](https://www.elastic.co/logstash) instead of inventing bicycle. It is stable, mature, scalable, and production-ready.

Answer (score 0):

easy solution and another way with findall() method:

```
import re
def show_time_of_pid(line):
  pattern = r"(\w+ \d+ \d+:\d+:\d+)+.*?\[(\d+)\]"
  result = re.findall(pattern, line)
  return "{} pid:{}".format(result[0][0], result[0][1])
```

Output:

```
Jul 6 14:01:23 pid:29440
Jul 6 14:02:08 pid:29187
Jul 6 14:02:09 pid:29187
Jul 6 14:03:01 pid:29440
Jul 6 14:03:40 pid:29807
Jul 6 14:04:01 pid:29440
Jul 6 14:05:01 pid:29440
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this problem:

```
import re
def show_time_of_pid(line):
  pattern = r"(\w*\s\d\s\d.......).*\[(\d....)"
  result = re.search(pattern, line)
  return "{} pid:{}".format(result[1], result[2])
#Here is my output:
Jul 6 14:01:23 pid:29440
Jul 6 14:02:08 pid:29187
Jul 6 14:02:09 pid:29187
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its the simplest i have ever seen

```
import re
def show_time_of_pid(line):
  pattern = r"(\w.*:\d+).*\[(\d+)\]"
  result = re.search(pattern, line)
  return "{} pid:{}".format(result[1],result[2])

print(show_time_of_pid("Jul 6 14:01:23 computer.name CRON[29440]: USER (good_user)")) # Jul 6 14:01:23 pid:29440

print(show_time_of_pid("Jul 6 14:02:08 computer.name jam_tag=psim[29187]: (UUID:006)")) # Jul 6 14:02:08 pid:29187

print(show_time_of_pid("Jul 6 14:02:09 computer.name jam_tag=psim[29187]: (UUID:007)")) # Jul 6 14:02:09 pid:29187

print(show_time_of_pid("Jul 6 14:03:01 computer.name CRON[29440]: USER (naughty_user)")) # Jul 6 14:03:01 pid:29440

print(show_time_of_pid("Jul 6 14:03:40 computer.name cacheclient[29807]: start syncing from \"0xDEADBEEF\"")) # Jul 6 14:03:40 pid:29807

print(show_time_of_pid("Jul 6 14:04:01 computer.name CRON[29440]: USER (naughty_user)")) # Jul 6 14:04:01 pid:29440

print(show_time_of_pid("Jul 6 14:05:01 computer.name CRON[29440]: USER (naughty_user)")) # Jul 6 14:05:01 pid:29440
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way

```
import re

def show_time_of_pid(line):
  pattern = r"(^\w+ \d+ \d+:\d+:\d+)(.*)(\[\d+\])"
  result = re.search(pattern, line)
  return ("{} pid:{}").format(result[1],result[3])

print(show_time_of_pid("Jul 6 14:01:23 computer.name CRON[29440]: USER (good_user)")) # Jul 6 14:01:23 pid:29440

print(show_time_of_pid("Jul 6 14:02:08 computer.name jam_tag=psim[29187]: (UUID:006)")) # Jul 6 14:02:08 pid:29187

print(show_time_of_pid("Jul 6 14:02:09 computer.name jam_tag=psim[29187]: (UUID:007)")) # Jul 6 14:02:09 pid:29187

print(show_time_of_pid("Jul 6 14:03:01 computer.name CRON[29440]: USER (naughty_user)")) # Jul 6 14:03:01 pid:29440

print(show_time_of_pid("Jul 6 14:03:40 computer.name cacheclient[29807]: start syncing from \"0xDEADBEEF\"")) # Jul 6 14:03:40 pid:29807

print(show_time_of_pid("Jul 6 14:04:01 computer.name CRON[29440]: USER (naughty_user)")) # Jul 6 14:04:01 pid:29440

print(show_time_of_pid("Jul 6 14:05:01 computer.name CRON[29440]: USER (naughty_user)")) # Jul 6 14:05:01 pid:29440
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my code:

```
import re
def show_time_of_pid(line):
 pattern = r"^(\w{3}.*:[\d]+).*\[(\d+)\]"
 result = re.search(pattern, line)
 return "{} pid:{}".format(result[1], result[2])
#Here my output:
 Jul 6 14:02:08 pid:29187
 Jul 6 14:02:09 pid:29187
 Jul 6 14:03:01 pid:29440
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

My implementation is getting only 14 characters in the first capture group and  getting only digits in second group. Special thanks to Joshua Omolewa for regex of the words in the middle :)

```
import re
def show_time_of_pid(line):
  pattern = r"([A-Za-z0-9: ]{14,14}) [\w].*\[([\d]+)\]"
  result = re.search(pattern, line)
  return result[1] + " pid:" + result[2]
```